# Concave strict increasing differentiable weight function stronger than root or ln functions?

Tags: functions

I am looking for a weight function $\phi$

- concave
- strict increasing
- differentiable

that solves the following:

$$\phi(25)-\phi(18.25) < \phi(18.25) - \phi(16) \tag{1}$$

The idea is to give greater weight to lower numbers - enough so that (1) is solved.

To my surprise a number of root and logarithm functions didn't do the trick of fulfilling (1). So what other similar weight functions are there?

Comment: Try a [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).  $F(x)=\frac 1{1+e^{-x}}$ works, for instance.

Comment: @lulu Great. Do you happen to know similar functions not bound from above?

Comment: Not offhand.  Maybe just multiplying the logistic function by $\sqrt x$ works.  Certainly looks negatively convex for a wide range of $x$ (not sure if it is strictly negatively convex or not).

Comment: Another one is $1-e^x$.